# Web pages with the same name but different extensions, where does the browser go?

Tags: .htaccess, url, web

I have multiple pages with the same name, `test.html` and `test.php`

I have my htaccess modified so that .html and .php files can be accessed without the extension attached.

I noticed that when I do it with my website, I am taken to the `test.php` page but is this standard or is it determined based on other factors?

Comment: This is a serversetting. Don't think you can set per folder (ie as renter of a server), so If you are just renting then accept whatever. If you set the server up yourself, then configure it to your liking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Apache web server the *DirectoryIndex* directive in the Apache configuration file, **httpd.conf**, is used to determine in what order files are searched for and then served to the requester.

Here is an example of what it might look like if you wanted to have an html file served before a php file when both were present in a directory.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```